# Prevent auto-opening of NI-Palette and Properties windows while opening res files

Tags: android, android-studio

How to prevent the auto-opening of the two windows `NI-Palette` and `Properties` in `Android Studio` when opening any xml files [for ex: layout or menu or any file in where these two windows can be used]

as they just auto-open after opening the xml file!

I am using `Android studio 2.2.3`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Fixed in:

```
Android Studio 2.3.3
Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

I did that by removing it from sidebar.

[image]

And it worked for both `Properties` & `NI-Palette` when opening any xml files **in text mode**!! *even after restarting the Android Studio.*

But, ***In Design mode***, Just `Properties` removes and `NI-Palette` is still showing after opening xml files in Design mode.

I'm not pretty sure, But it can be a bug maybe..

Comment: Thanks for you answer  but it is not what i need , i need to leave them in the sidebar to easily show/hide them!